# C sets of linked-lists (abstract data type)

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am trying to write an abstract data type to represent sets of integer items using linked lists.

I am getting the following errors:

```
ERROR undeclared identifier 'linkedListSet'

error #2152: Unknown field 'code' of '(incomplete) struct LinkedListSet'.
```

and feel I must be breaking some basic rule with functions, structs and pointers but I really can't figure it out. Below is my code with error message lines commented.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct linkedListElement{
    int data;
    struct linkedListElement * next;
};

struct linkedListSet {
    //struct linkedListElement * firstElement;
    struct linkedListElement * header;
    struct linkedListElement * current;
    struct linkedListElement * temp;
    int code;
};

struct linkedListSet * createdSet (){
    struct linkedListSet * newSet = malloc(sizeof(linkedListSet));
    //ERROR undeclared identifier 'linkedListSet'

    newSet->header->data = 0;
    newSet->header->next = NULL;

    return newSet;
}

int addItem (struct LinkedListSet * setPtr, int info){
    struct linkedListElement * newElementPtr;

    setPtr->code = 3;
    //error #2152: Unknown field 'code' of '(incomplete) struct LinkedListSet'.
    return 1;
};

int main(){
    return (0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`linkedListSet` should be `struct linkedListSet`:

```
struct linkedListSet * newSet = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedListSet));
```

`LinkedListSet` should be `linkedListSet`.

```
int addItem (struct linkedListSet * setPtr, int info)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - basic errors but I couldn't see them at all!

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing structs like so

```
typedef struct /* my struct tag */ {
int a;
int b;
} MyStructType;
```

And later

```
MyStructType * mystruct;
mystruct->a = 34;
// etc...
```